# How do I use an If Else statement in batch

Tags: batch-file

currently i'm writing a batch file for a simple register and login system.
I want to make it so that the program will test if 2 variables are the same and if they are different. Here is what I have so far

```css
@echo off
title Login
:a
cls
mode con: lines=10 cols=25
echo _________________________
echo     Select Your Choice
echo      1) Login
echo      2) Register
echo _________________________
set /p begi=:
if '%begi%'=='2' goto reg
if '%begi%'=='1' goto sign

:reg
cls
set u=
set /p u=Enter Your Username:
pause>nul
cls
set p=
set /p p=Enter your Password:
pause>nul
echo %u%>user.txt
echo %p%>pass.txt
pause>nul
goto a

:sign
cls
set /p "un="<user.txt
set /p "pa="<pass.txt
echo Enter you username
set uu=
set /p uu=:
pause>nul
if "%uu%"=="up" goto pa else goto mess


:pa
cls
echo Enter you password
set pp=
set /p pp=:
pause>nul
if "%pp%"=="%pa%" goto menu else goto mess


:menu
cls
color 2f
echo YAY
pause>nul
exit

:mess
color 4f
echo Access Denied
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: Where is your problem?

Comment: my problem is at :sign. I dont know how to use the IF ELSE statement to test between two variables.

Comment: Try next: `if "%pp%"=="%pa%" (goto :menu) else (goto :mess)`. [Learn more here](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: also you get `%un%` from file and `%uu%` from user, but compare `%uu%` with `%up%`. Typing error?